# How to make div page around the image and icon (Bootstrap 4)

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I want to try to make a div page with an icon around the text and button but it won't make an icon beside the text just like this(It also affects the button). I already tried using Flex documentation d-flex justify-content-around in div class but it doesn't work. I'm using Bootstrap 4. Here's the result :

The Result:
[image: The Result]

The Result I wanted:
[image: The Result I wanted]

Here's the coding :

**Home.html**

```css
div.page {
  padding: 10px 20px;
  background: #FDFDFD;
  width: 280px;
  height: 180px;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
  border-radius: 32px;
}

p.page {
  color: #252525;
  margin-left: 20px;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: 'Roboto',sans-serif;
}

button.show {
  border-radius: 32px;
  font-weight:bold;
  margin-right: 80px;
  margin-top: 30px;
  border: 3px solid #3379E4;
  text-align:center;
  padding: 5px;
  background: #3379E4;
  width: 50%;
  color: #FDFDFD;
  font-family:'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

i.page {
  font-size: 36px;
  color: #3379E4;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ho+j7jyWK8fNQe+A12Hb8AhRq26LrZ/JpcUGGOn+Y7RsweNrtN/tE3MoK7ZeZDyx" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.1/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-+4zCK9k+qNFUR5X+cKL9EIR+ZOhtIloNl9GIKS57V1MyNsYpYcUrUeQc9vNfzsWfV28IaLL3i96P9sdNyeRssA==" crossorigin="anonymous" />


<div class="container mt-5">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col text-center">
      <div class="d-flex">
        <div class="page mr-auto p-2">
          <i class="page fas fa-calculator text-right"></i>
          <p class="page text-left">AK</p>
          <button class="show">Show</button>
        </div>
        <div class="page p-2">
          <i class="page fas fa-laptop text-right"></i>
          <p class="page text-left">TKJ</p>
          <button class="show">Show</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/09/18/14/21/swimmer-1678307__340.jpg" class="img-fluid" width="500">
      <div class="d-flex">
        <div class="page mr-auto p-2">
          <i class="page fas fa-store text-right"></i>
          <p class="page text-left">PM</p>
          <button class="show">Show</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Thank you for helping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I add custom css that you could see by the bottom of the css:

```
/**** CSS ADDED ****/
.img-fluid {
  margin: -10vh auto;
}
.z-index-1{
  z-index:1;
}
```

**I recommand to not use class: `.img-fluid` as I did but to create another class with this negative margin. Here it is really just for the demo**

Then I added classes in follow:

```
<div class="col text-center">

<div class="d-flex">
```

To make it like:

```
<div class="col text-center d-flex flex-column">

<div class="d-flex z-index-1">
```

### Edit:

Rework structure of your card this way by dividing in 2 cols and some correction in CSS for icon font-size :

```
    <div class="page p-2 row">
      <div class="col-8">
        <p class="page text-left">TKJ</p>
        <button class="show">Show</button>
       </div>
      <div class="col-4 d-flex">
       <i class="page fas fa-laptop m-auto"></i>
     </div>
    </div>
```

### DEMO:

```css
div.page {
  padding: 10px 20px;
  background: #FDFDFD;
  width: 280px;
  height: 180px;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
  border-radius: 32px;
}

p.page {
  color: #252525;
  margin-left: 20px;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: 'Roboto',sans-serif;
}

button.show {
  border-radius: 32px;
  font-weight:bold;
  margin-right: 80px;
  margin-top: 30px;
  border: 3px solid #3379E4;
  text-align:center;
  padding: 5px;
  background: #3379E4;
  width: 100%;                /* CAHNGED FROM 50% TO 100% */
  color: #FDFDFD;
  font-family:'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

i.page {
  font-size: 4em;   /* Changed from 36px to 4em */
  color: #3379E4;
}

/**** CSS ADDED ****/
.img-fluid {
  margin: -10vh auto;
}
.z-index-1{
  z-index:1;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ho+j7jyWK8fNQe+A12Hb8AhRq26LrZ/JpcUGGOn+Y7RsweNrtN/tE3MoK7ZeZDyx" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.1/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-+4zCK9k+qNFUR5X+cKL9EIR+ZOhtIloNl9GIKS57V1MyNsYpYcUrUeQc9vNfzsWfV28IaLL3i96P9sdNyeRssA==" crossorigin="anonymous" />


<div class="container mt-5">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col text-center d-flex flex-column">
      <div class="d-flex z-index-1">
        <div class="page mr-auto p-2 row">
          <div class="col-8">
            <p class="page text-left">AK</p>
            <button class="show">Show</button>
          </div>
          <div class="col-4 d-flex">
            <i class="page fas fa-calculator m-auto"></i>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="page p-2 row">
          <div class="col-8">
            <p class="page text-left">TKJ</p>
            <button class="show">Show</button>
           </div>
          <div class="col-4 d-flex">
           <i class="page fas fa-laptop m-auto"></i>
         </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/09/18/14/21/swimmer-1678307__340.jpg" class="img-fluid" width="500">
      <div class="d-flex z-index-1">
        <div class="page mr-auto p-2 row">
          <div class="col-8">
            <p class="page text-left">PM</p>
            <button class="show">Show</button>
          </div>
          <div class="col-4 d-flex">
            <i class="page fas fa-store m-auto"></i>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help but what is z-index for?

Comment: z-index is use to show a front visual priority. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index  I would recommend you to not fix width of your image because on big screen your boxes will let your image. Or you should fix conatiner max-width. If you dont use z-index here then the 1st 2 image will go under the image

Comment: I already deleted the width in the class="img-fluid" and finally works like charm by changing the width to max-width with style.css but my icon and text still messed up even though I use Flex. I have given no-wrap in every icon to make it right ( "<i class="page fas fa-calculator no-wrap"></i>) but it suddenly goes beside the button